# Trying to populate telerik grid but the gird keeps showing up as empty

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

In Index.cshtml I have the following:

```
@{
    Html.Telerik().Grid<hekomaseru.Models.testdbEntities1>("testtable")
        .Name("grid1")
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Render();
}
```

And in HomeController.cs I do this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<int> abc = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        ViewData["testtable"] = abc;

        return View();
    }
```

For some reason though when everything loads up the grid is always empty (no records to display). Any ideas why it wouldn't work?

I have other telerik stuff working (namely the drop down menus) so I don't think it has anything to do specifically with that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid needs to bind to a list of objects. A list of ints won't work because they are value types. A list of strings will work like Lester said, but the only property is length. If you want a list of ints, you could add a class like this.

```
public class Numbers
{
  public Numbers(int number)
  {
    Num = number;
  }
  public int Num
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Then in the Controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<Numbers> abc = new List<Numbers>();
  abc.Add(new Numbers(1));
  abc.Add(new Numbers(2));
  abc.Add(new Numbers(3));
  abc.Add(new Numbers(4));
  abc.Add(new Numbers(5));

  return View(abc);
}
```

The View

```
@model List<Numbers>

@{
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid1")
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Render();
}
```

To make the grid more interesting, just add more properties to the Numbers class.

Answer (score 1):

I've only used the Telerik MVC controls briefly, but I've never binded to ViewData like that. Could you change it to:

```
@model IList<int>

@{
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid1")
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Render();
}
```

And your controller to:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<int> abc = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    return View(abc);
}
```

This is almost exactly how I'm binding so it should work.

Comment: I get an error when I do that: Compiler Error Message: CS0452: The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.ViewComponentFactory.Grid<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'

Comment: Looks like it's not happy with int. Try changing it to a list of strings.

Comment: Just did, it works now but it's not displaying the string content, instead its displaying how long each string is (so if the string is "abc" it shows '3' instead of "abc", and the column header is 'length') :S